# Получение нового сообщения от пользователя pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Есть часть кода

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_message_keyboard(message):
    if str(message.chat.id) == admin_token:
        if message.text == '❌Выход❌':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выполнено", reply_markup=admin_keyboard_close())
        elif message.text == 'Отправить сообщение всем':
           //////////////
        elif message.text == 'Добавить прогноз':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В разработке')
        elif message.text == 'Добавить прогноз в статистику':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В разработке')
```

Нужно сделать, чтоб при выборе "Отправить сообщение всем" сбрасывалось предыдущее сообщение(Отправить сообщение всем) и заменялась на то, что напишет пользователь. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Создай новую функцию с клавиатурой, в которую передашь значение message с помощью
`bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func_name)`.